# How to add activity Indicator to center of webView

Tags: swift

With this code I get indicator but to top left corner of webView and behind borders

(I have DetailView storyboard but want to write code programmatically)

```
var webView = WKWebView()
var detailItem : CountriesFinal?
var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    spinner.frame = CGRect(x: webView.frame.width / 2, y: webView.frame.height / 2, width: 10, height: 10)
    webView.addSubview(spinner)
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    webView.backgroundColor = .blue
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 125, y: 150, width: 250, height: 150)
    webView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    webView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    webView.backgroundColor = .blue

    self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

I notice that this line doesn't change anything and I thought it may be the solution:

```
  spinner.frame = CGRect(x: webView.frame.width / 2, y: webView.frame.height / 2, width: 10, height: 10)
```

I've tried to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of spinner to false but then whole webView disappear with purple warning " Layout Issues: Position and size are ambiguous for WKWebView."

[image]

UPDATED CODE(webVIew not showing):

```
   webView.frame = CGRect(x: 125, y: 150, width: 250, height: 150)
    
    webView.backgroundColor = .blue
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    
    
    webView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    webView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    webView.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    
    self.view.insertSubview(spinner, aboveSubview: webView)
    spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

Answer (score 2):

**In my opinion** `WKWebView` is one of the system views that should probably be a "leaf" in your view hiercarchy.  It is very complex in the content it manages and may not like it if you add subviews.

Instead of putting the spinner inside the `WKWebView`, I would probably put it into a view that is a sibling and stack it in front of the WebView in the z-order.  It will float above the web view, but look like it is inside of it.

Here's a Playground I threw together that demonstrates the idea:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { error in
    debugPrint(error)
}

let controller = UIViewController()

let webView = WKWebView()
webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))

let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

controller.view.addSubview(webView)
webView.frame = controller.view.bounds

controller.view.insertSubview(spinner, aboveSubview: webView)

spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller

spinner.startAnimating()
```

Comment: If Im right, with this changes applied to my code the spinner should be at center of webView but  they are not connected and I will only need to implement webView "didFinish" to make it disappear?

Comment: Yes.  What you would probably do is add features to the viewController that owns both of the views, have the web view tell the controller when it's finished loading, and the controller can tell the spinner when to stop.

Comment: Thank you but it gets an error saying:"Unable to activate constraint with anchors because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."

Comment: For my scheme to work, the `WKWebView` and `UIActivityIndicatorView` both have to be subviews of the same view.  In my playground the UIViewController owns a view that is the parent of both the webView and the spinner.  It then grows the webView so that it completely covers the parent view.

Comment: I will update my code it has no errors but webView is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Working code. Changed place of addSubview

```
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 125, y: 150, width: 250, height: 150)
    
    webView.backgroundColor = .blue
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    webView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    webView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    webView.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    
    self.webView.addSubview(self.spinner)//first we need to add subview then make center or something
    spinner.center = CGPoint(x: webView.bounds.width / 2, y: webView.bounds.height / 2)
 
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).